# OnClick with custom adapter and Listview

Tags: android, listview, onclick, adapter

Looked at lots of other posts and tried several variations but no luck so far...

Getting a NPE with the following custom list adapter defined as so:

```
public ListView tripList;
....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ....

        // build a listView adapter
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"About to create listView...");
        tripList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"ListView created...");

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"About to create adapter...");
        tripAdapter = new tripListAdapter(this, tripCur);
        setListAdapter(tripAdapter);

    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trip_display);
```

...and adaptor has this:

```
// custom list adaptor class
private class tripListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    //private final Cursor dataC;
    private final LayoutInflater vi;

    public tripListAdapter(Context con, Cursor c) {
        // super constructor thingy
        super(con, c);
        //dataC = c;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(con);

    }

@Override
    public View getView (int position, View tripView, ViewGroup parent){

        Log.i(LOGTAG,"In getView...");
        // Create a message handling object as an anonymous class.
        //mTripClickHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {

// NPE ERROR ON THIS NEXT LINE (line 228):
        tripList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Do something in response to the click
                // Enable other buttons
                togBtns(true);
```

LogCat:

```
06-13 09:47:49.195: I/WIBBLE(864): ListView created...
06-13 09:47:49.195: I/WIBBLE(864): About to create adapter...
06-13 09:47:49.285: I/WIBBLE(864): OnResume with this many rows returned by cursor: 3
06-13 09:47:49.285: I/WIBBLE(864): In the loop, so cursor is not null....
06-13 09:47:49.375: I/WIBBLE(864): In getView...
06-13 09:47:49.387: D/AndroidRuntime(864): Shutting down VM
06-13 09:47:49.387: W/dalvikvm(864): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at  com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayTripsActivity$tripListAdapter.getView(DisplayTripsActivity.java:228)
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
06-13 09:47:49.505: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
```

Any advice gratefully received.

EDIT: if I replace:

```
//tripList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

with:

```
tripList = getListView();
```

...I move on (see WIBBLE messages) but get another NPE, although seems to be in some system routine:

```
06-13 10:26:49.825: I/WIBBLE(934): About to create listView...
06-13 10:26:49.865: I/WIBBLE(934): ListView created...
06-13 10:26:49.865: I/WIBBLE(934): About to create adapter...
06-13 10:26:49.945: I/WIBBLE(934): OnResume with this many rows returned by cursor: 3
06-13 10:26:49.945: I/WIBBLE(934): In the loop, so cursor is not null....
06-13 10:26:50.035: I/WIBBLE(934): In getView...
06-13 10:26:50.035: I/WIBBLE(934): Leaving getView...
06-13 10:26:50.035: D/AndroidRuntime(934): Shutting down VM
06-13 10:26:50.035: W/dalvikvm(934): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at  android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
06-13 10:26:50.185: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
```

...and lots of other lines, none referencing my code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be setting `onItemClickListener` from the `Adapter`. The `Adapter` is only concerned with creating the individual list item views. Set the `onItemClickListener` from your `Activity` (or `Fragment`) after the view has been inflated.

It looks like you aren't currently setting your Activities view, which is why the tripList ListView is NULL. Use `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` to set the view to an xml layout.

You may want to post a larger portion of your code. Is this an Activity or a Fragment? Are you extending a base Activity/Fragment, or something else like ListActivity/ListFragment. I wonder because you are accessing android's R file instead of your own (android.R.id.list vs R.id.list)

**Update**

Ok, I've answered my own question. You are using a ListActivity (or ListFragment) which is why you are using android's R file. I would change that to `getListView()` instead of `findViewById`. And still I would move the `setOnItemClickListener` and post the new NPE exceptions as that is the proper way to do this.

Comment: A previous answer specifically said to put the onClick inside getView of the adapter, for a custom adapter. I have already tried with the onClick in the activity and got other NPE errors. There is a setContentView call - it's just the next line but I didn't bother putting it in here...

Comment: I've written plenty of custom adapters and never needed to set the click listener in the adapter. Are you extending ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter, ... ?

Comment: CursorAdapter  - admittedly, when I had the onClick in the activity, I did at least get the list populated but there was no response to the click, as if the onClick didn't exist. That's when I started looking on here and saw the suggestion of using getView...

Comment: Added a bit more code - don't like putting too much in or it gets too tricky to follow...

Comment: If you are extending ListActivity, you can't (or at least shouldn't) setContentView

Comment: OK, if I remove (?) the setContentView call, I get a fatal 'Unable to start Activity' error when creating the adapter. However, when I use getListView, I do go past my previous error but now got a new one - I'll add the LogCat to the original post...

Comment: Does your xml layout have a ListView with the id android:id/list ?

Comment: Yes - I have had the list populated when I had the onClick in the activity, but the onCLick itself never worked then.

Comment: The problem is you are setting the onItemClick everytime a new list item view is rendered. You only need to set it once. Post your full code, I can't help you any further.

Comment: Hmm, that does sound stupid...OK, I'll put it back and post a new question with the other errors I had. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning your tripView variable to ListView, you use:

```
tripList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Try changing this line to:

```
tripList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Instead of searching the `android.R` for the proper item (where it probably doesn't exit), look for your ListView item in the R file generated when building your project.

Be sure to rebuild your project before running it.

Comment: If I do that, I get a 'list cannot be resolved or is not a field' compilation error.

Comment: Is this a `ListActivity` or just a regular `Activity` class with a `ListView` view added to it??